# Azure Speech Recognition - use binary / hexadecimal data instead of WAV file path

Tags: python, azure, binary, hex, speech-recognition

I am looking for a way to use Azure Speech Recognition API, passing a binary / hexadecimal data instead of WAV file path as argument.

"raw_data" is a hexadecimal data that represents a small WAV file:

```
raw_data = self.audio.get_wav_data()
```

Saving to a WAV file in disk (which is not what I am looking for):

```
main_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
wav_file = os.path.join(main_dir, 'output.wav')
with open(wav_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(raw_data)
```

Setting up the config and consuming Azure's API for speech recognition:

```
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="<subscription>", region="westeurope")
speech_config.speech_recognition_language="pt-BR"
audio_config = speechsdk.AudioConfig(filename=wav_file)
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()
user_request = result.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Push Stream

**Sample** is present below :

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py

Here you configure the Stream that will be used for the recognition.

```
 stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream()
 audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream)
```

The sample refers reading a wave file & converting to binary data. Rather you could use the stream.read() method and load the binary data in the above configured Stream

```
frames = wav_fh.readframes(n_bytes // 2)
        print('read {} bytes'.format(len(frames)))
        if not frames:
            break

    stream.write(frames)
```