# Azure speech to text REST API V3 binary data

Tags: azure, rest, text-to-speech, azure-speech

I'm trying to use Azure Speech to text service. In the documentation I'm confronted with examples, that use **V1** API version:
`https://$region.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1`

And basically every link to proper documentation is for the **V3** API.

`https://{endpoint}/speechtotext/v3.0`

In this **V1** example you can easily send your file as **binary**.

```
curl --location --request POST \
"https://$region.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US" \
--header "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key" \
--header "Content-Type: audio/wav" \
--data-binary $audio_file
```

But I **could not** figure it out how to provide an `wordLevelTimestampsEnabled=true` parameter for getting word level timestamps.

On the other hand, I tried using the **V3** API, and I can easily provide `wordLevelTimestampsEnabled=true` parameter, but I couldn't figure out how to send binary file data.

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.0/transcriptions' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key' --data-raw '{
  "contentUrls": [
    "https://url-to-file.dev/test-file.wav"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "diarizationEnabled": false,
    "wordLevelTimestampsEnabled": true,
    "punctuationMode": "DictatedAndAutomatic",
    "profanityFilterMode": "Masked"
  },
  "locale": "pl-PL",
  "displayName": "Transcription using default model for pl-PL"
}'
```

Is there a way to pass a binary file and also get word level timestamps with `wordLevelTimestampsEnabled=true` parameter?

Comment: Browsing through the [documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateTranscription), it looks like you can't upload the binary file directly. You must provide a URL to the file via the `contentUrls` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass a binary file and also get word level timestamps with `wordLevelTimestampsEnabled=true` parameter?

As suggested by [Code Different](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different), converting a comment as a community wiki answer to help community members who might face a similar issue.

As per the [documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateTranscription), binary file can't be uploaded directly. You should provide URL via `contentUrls` property.

For example:

```
{
  "contentUrls": [
    "<URL to an audio file to transcribe>",
  ],
  "properties": {
    "diarizationEnabled": false,
    "wordLevelTimestampsEnabled": true,
    "punctuationMode": "DictatedAndAutomatic",
    "profanityFilterMode": "Masked"
  },
  "locale": "en-US",
  "displayName": "Transcription of file using default model for en-US"
}
```

You can refer to [Speech-to-text REST API v3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text), [cognitive-services-speech-sdk](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/182fabecee81a4af948e6a049db84da60cb09181/samples/batch/js/node/main.js) and [Azure Speech Recognition - use binary / hexadecimal data instead of WAV file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568000/azure-speech-recognition-use-binary-hexadecimal-data-instead-of-wav-file-pat)